# How spark is behaving this Type Ascription in select query in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following columns that i want to select dynamically. 
so i have

```
 val columnLists = Seq("STORENO", "TICKETNO", "POSNO")
 val temp = columnLists.map(col):_*

 val newDF = oldDF.select(temp) // Won't compile
```

where
 this works fine if i directly wrote this.

```
 val newDF = oldDF.select(columnLists.map(col):_*)
```

Why it behaves like or am i missing something here.

Comment: `: _*` is an special kind of "type ascription", because it turns any kind of **Seq** into a ** varargs** _(for example `def foo(args: String*)`)_. Since a **varargs** does not exists as a type, and in the body of the function it is nothing more than a **Seq**, the `: _*` is not really changing a type, but is just syntax to tell the compiler that you want to pass that **Seq** directly to the method. As such, ` val temp = columnLists.map(col):_*` is a no-op, `temp` is just another **Seq**. `: _*` has to be used on the function call site always.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez for the explanation.